# Do the non-dimensionalizing equations that result from the Buckingham-$\pi$ algorithm necessarily have a unique solution?

Tags: dimensional-analysis

Consider the Buckingham-$\pi$ algorithm:

1. Let us say that we have $n+1$ relevant variables: $\{Q_0, ..., Q_n\}$.
2. Let us say that we can define their dimensions in terms of $k$ basic dimensions.
3. So, we select $k$ variables that are independent in terms of their dimensions, that is:

$$\left(\prod_{z = 0}^{k-1}\left[Q_{n-k+1 + z}\right]^{c_z} = 1\right) \equiv (\forall z : c_z = 0),$$ where $[Q_a]$ is the dimension of the $a$th variable4. Then, when we form the $\Pi$ groups, so we have:

$$ [Q_a]\left(\prod_{z = 0}^{k-1}\left[Q_{n-k+1 + z}\right]^{c_z}\right) = [\Pi_a] = 1$$

Do the $k$ equations for $c_z$ that we get out of this step necessarily have a unique solution? I know that they can have a unique solution at times, based on the examples I have run into, but if they don't have a unique solution, is that a sign of an error?